# How to make ExceptionNotifier work with delayed_job in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, exception-notification

I'd like ExceptionNotifier to send out an email when an exception happens in a delayed job, just like for other exceptions. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Interesting question, in looking I came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104093/exception-notification-for-delayed-job and http://groups.google.com/group/delayed_job/browse_thread/thread/646314145a69360b?fwc=1&pli=1

Comment: Yep, I've seen both of those but I think these solutions only work with Rails 2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do this with Rails 3.2.6, delayed_job 3.0.3 and [exception_notification](https://rubygems.org/gems/exception_notification) 2.6.1 gem

```
# In config/environments/production.rb or config/initializers/delayed_job.rb

# Optional but recommended for less future surprises.
# Fail at startup if method does not exist instead of later in a background job 
[[ExceptionNotifier::Notifier, :background_exception_notification]].each do |object, method_name|
  raise NoMethodError, "undefined method `#{method_name}' for #{object.inspect}" unless object.respond_to?(method_name, true)
end

# Chain delayed job's handle_failed_job method to do exception notification
Delayed::Worker.class_eval do 
  def handle_failed_job_with_notification(job, error)
    handle_failed_job_without_notification(job, error)
    # only actually send mail in production
    if Rails.env.production?
      # rescue if ExceptionNotifier fails for some reason
      begin
        ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error)
      rescue Exception => e
        Rails.logger.error "ExceptionNotifier failed: #{e.class.name}: #{e.message}"
        e.backtrace.each do |f|
          Rails.logger.error "  #{f}"
        end
        Rails.logger.flush
      end
    end
  end 
  alias_method_chain :handle_failed_job, :notification 
end
```

It's probably a good idea to load this code in all environments to catch errors after bundle update etc before they reach production. I do this by having a `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` file but you could duplicate the code for each `config/environments/*` environment.

Another tip is to tune the delayed job config a bit as default you may get a lot of duplicate exception mails when job fails.

```
# In config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
```

**Update** I had some problems with the `delayed_job` daemon silently exiting and it turned out to be when `ExceptionNotifier` fails to send mail and no one rescued the exception. Now the code rescues and log them.

Comment: I'd recommend using the official exception notification gem at https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification

Comment: Ah ok, will update to that. I was using the rails3 gem as there seamd  to be some rails 3 issues with the official version at the time.

Comment: +1 This approach works with Rails 3.2.6, Delayed Job 3.0.3, and Exception Notification 2.6.1.  Initially I thought adding an error method using the built-in hook would be a cleaner approach, but that would have to be defined for each job class, and defining it generically for `PerformableMethod` didn't work due to how `delegate` is used.

Comment: Nice. I actually updated to the same versions the other day but didn't remember to update the answer.

Comment: I've added a ```, :data => {:job => job}``` to the method call so that I have a bit more details…

Comment: To get notified ONLY when last attempt failed I add:

      `ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(error)  if job.attempts == Delayed::Worker.max_attempts`

in place of:
        `ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error)`

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @MattiasWadman answer, since exception_notification 4.0 [there's a new way to handle manual notify](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/tree/v4.0.0#background-notifications). So instead of:

```
ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error)
```

use

```
ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(error)
```

Comment: will this also be processed in te background?

Comment: @DaniëlZwijnenburg The method is being called by delayed_job, so yes

Answer (score 4):

Another way to handle exceptions (put as an initializer):

```
class DelayedErrorHandler < Delayed::Plugin

  callbacks do |lifecycle|

    lifecycle.around(:invoke_job) do |job, *args, &block|

      begin
        block.call(job, *args)
      rescue Exception => e

        # ...Process exception here...

        raise e
      end
    end
  end
end

Delayed::Worker.plugins << DelayedErrorHandler
```

Comment: I think this is cleanest solution. BTW other solutions wont work in the future, because alias_method_chain is deprecated in Rails 5

Answer (score 3):

`alias_method_chain` no longer exists in Rails 5.

Here's the new (proper) way to do this using Ruby 2's `prepend`

```
# In config/initializers/delayed_job.rb
module CustomFailedJob
  def handle_failed_job(job, error)
    super
    ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(error, data: {job: job})
  end
end

class Delayed::Worker
  prepend CustomFailedJob
end
```

Comment: This is the answer which worked for me, running Rails 4.2.

Comment: `Delayed::Worker.prepend CustomFailedJob` can be used directly

Answer (score 2):

For exception_notification 3.0.0 change:

```
ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error)
```

to:

```
ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(error).deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

simpler and updated answer:

```
# Chain delayed job's handle_failed_job method to do exception notification
Delayed::Worker.class_eval do
  def handle_failed_job_with_notification job, error
    handle_failed_job_without_notification job, error
    ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception error,
      data: {job: job, handler: job.handler} rescue nil
  end 
  alias_method_chain :handle_failed_job, :notification
end
```

And test on console with:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue (JS=Struct.new(:a){ def perform; raise 'here'; end }).new(1)
```

Comment: @AlterLagos I think you misunderstand alias_method_chain.