# Rails exception notifier in rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, error-handling, rake, exception-notification

I have a simple rails application with a few controller and some rake tasks. A couple of tasks are executed by cron configured with [whenever gem](http://github.com/javan/whenever).

One of my task is executed daily and sometime it raises an exception and by default I receive this warning by cron

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `parameterize' for nil:NilClass

Tasks: TOP => mailboxes:clean_processed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I want to debug what's happening and for this reason I've just installed this [exception notification](https://rubygems.org/gems/exception_notification) gem with this line in my `Gemfile`

```
gem "exception_notification", "~> 2.4.1", :require => 'exception_notifier'
```

and configured it in my `application.rb` file with

```
# enable exception notification
config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
                      :email_prefix => "[MyAppName] ",
                      :sender_address => %{"notifier" <report@example.com>},
                      :exception_recipients => %w{me@example.com}
```

Since this gem is a rack middleware it only works for web requests and not for rake tasks. I'd like to enable it also for rake tasks and I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/551136) which do the job.

It works, however it's not DRY, I need to repeat gem configuration in that method and I also need to change all my rake tasks to enclose their statements in a block as in

```
exception_notify { actual_task_code }
```

Is there any better way to solve this?

P.S. If I need to change the notification gem would not be a problem because I added only a few lines of code to my project.

P.P.S. I know that I can also change the rake line in the crontab to add a `--trace` option, but I don't like that solution, cause exception notifier imho is a better solution which helps also in web code.

**Update** I just found out this related question: [exception_notification for delayed_job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104093/exception-notification-for-delayed-job) but both the answers use a similar trick.

I'm going to try with an online service like Airbrake (formerly known as hoptoad) or Exceptional, but both of them are paid services...

**Update 2**: I tried the [Airbrake App](http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home), very nice application, but it suffer for the same problem, I still need to hack the Rakefile to notify exceptions from rake tasks. However the hack is less dry because you just need this code:

```
# notify exceptions
def exception_notify
  yield
rescue Exception => exception
  HoptoadNotifier.notify exception
  raise exception
end
```

There is no need to repeat any configuration parameter. I think I can't do better than this to get notified of exceptions in rake tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Airbrake gem [patches Rake](https://github.com/thoughtbot/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake/rake_handler.rb) to allow rescuing, so it already does what I'm asking...

Comment: To enable logging of Rake errors, you'll need to add the line ```config.rescue_rake_exceptions = true``` to ```conifg/initializers/airbrake.rb```.

Answer (score 15):

Create a task.rb file in config/initializers, which monkey patches Rake::Task#execute to include the functionality of exception_notify:

```
module Rake
  class Task
    alias :orig_execute :execute
    def execute(args=nil)
      orig_execute(args)
    rescue Exception => exception
      # Exception notification stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Tested with Rails 3.0.12, Rake 0.9.2.2.

Comment: Please note that you need to require "rake/task", or Rails' console will no longer run due to a NameError.

Answer (score 7):

there is new easier solution: gem https://github.com/nikhaldi/exception_notification-rake

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this suggestion; it works great for me since I only have one cron task at the moment.

To DRY it up, you could turn the configuration into constants, perhaps via `APP_CONFIG`:
https://github.com/cjbottaro/app_config

In addition, you could extend whatever class takes care of `task :... do` to wrap everything in `exception_notify { }`.

Comment: I'm interested in you last hint, could you expand a little bit?

Comment: You'de have to dig into how rake tasks work, deeper into the Rails framework. I don't know the details either. But you could extend those classed to do whatever you like.