# How to setup a generic error/exception handler callback in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling

I’m working on this issue: [Rails exception notifier in rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161374/rails-exception-notifier-in-rake-tasks)

**My question:** Is there any function/plugin/gem/whatever to setup a generic error/exception handler callback as in PHP with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [`set_exception_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)?

I need a way to register a callback function used as a catchall outside any `begin .. rescue .. end` block. For example:

```
def my_handler *args
  # exception processing code here
end

some_magic_method my_handler

raise "An Exception" # this will be handled by my_handler
```

In PHP this could be achieved with the `set_exception_handler` function. Is there any such function in Ruby/Rails?

If such feature exists I could solve my previous issue in a simple way.

A Rails-only solution would be fine for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Ruby provides a way to do this, either with exceptions or with throw/catch. In general, doing something this way is a code smell and something to avoid. It makes control flow extremely hard to figure out. I would try to find some other way to approach the problem if at all possible.

Comment: I'm agree in part with your point, what I'm asking for is conceptually similar to [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) class method used in ActionController but in the top level part of a program. It could be very useful and DRY in some cases.

Comment: Agreed, there are times it's useful. That's why it's a code smell, not an anti-pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the HTTP Request-handling cycle you may use an around filter in your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter do |controller, action|
    action.call
  rescue ExceptionXPTO
     # ... handle the exception ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I know that, but nice hint. However that won't solve the generic issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to my issue which works for the simple case I mentioned in the question. However this can not catch the exception, but it can be useful if someone needs only exception logging or reporting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

at_exit do
  if $!
    puts "Program ended with an exception #{$!.message}"
    puts $!.backtrace.join("\n")
    # or log the exception here
  end
end

loop do
  value = rand(3)
  puts "Value is #{value}"
  break if value == 2 
  raise "An Exception" if value == 0
end

puts "Program ended normally"
```